# How would one train a group of women, who previously had no idea of the existence of aircraft, into pilots?

Tags: medieval, combat, aircraft, training

All the fantasy races like Elves, Dwarves, god-like beings and Demons have all grown sick of humanity’s shenanigans. They started a war of extermination against Humans, eventually confining them to an area smaller than Madagascar. The conquest of Humans was relatively easy; the Humans have no magic while the others do. It was also made even easier by the fact that there was no technological disparity between the races.

This all changed when humans from our universe started pouring in.

First, they made armor obsolete, by way of inventing the rifle. Though humanity was cornered into such a small space they still had divided kingdoms and therefore, war. Thus, they still needed to be united in order to advance even more quickly. Though the land was small, it had vast amounts of untapped resources. This is why, once reunited, humanity began to advance by leaps and bounds.

Better mining equipment allowed them to collect vast amount of resources in a shorter time. Steam poured into the sky by the tons as they started a new industrial revolution. Second, public services began popping up. Things like electricity, plumbing, roadways, etc.

Overpopulation was kind of a problem, so they began expanding outwards bit by bit. The other races took notice of this and started a new war, this time to eradicate humanity for sure. By this time, humanity was already at the WW1 era. This meant they had access to artillery, primitive tanks, and machine guns.

A terrible war emerged, for the other races at least. Trench warfare ensured that none of them shall pass. Rows and rows of medieval warriors with only the aid of magic were cut down by machine gun fire, like Death himself went and scythed them down like wheat.

Unfortunately, humanity also experienced heavy defeats and casualties. The elven warriors had enchanted arrows that can fly at speeds similar to the bullets used by the human troops. The dwarves built steampunk-esque machines that could tank machine gun fire and spit out flames. The god-like beings used incredible magic to move the earth to their advantage, blocking bullets by making a dirt wall in the middle of no man’s land. Demons loved to posses the senior officers, forcing them to command their own troops to charge to their doom.

To end this war early, humans needed to attack the Command center of the other races. Once the Command center was gone, the enemy troops would fall into disarray. While they’re all mucking about confused, humanity will perform a massive encirclement movement. Cutting off the enemy troops from their supply line.

The problem, was that it couldn’t be reached by the artillery and the lines won’t move. The Command center was also heavily protected by magical shields that could shrug off a bombardment by artillery. Dragons owned by the god-like beings patrolled the skies above the plains surrounding the Command center, attacking human tanks that made it this close to the leadership.

It was decided that humanity needed an air force. But where to get pilots? All of the able bodied men were either in the trenches or working at factories. A group of widows suddenly knocked on the government office’s door. They wanted to join the military to avenge their husbands who died in the war.

And so, they were drafted into the air force. They would perform bombing missions on the enemy’s command center. Like the [Night Witches](https://www.google.com.ph/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=2ahUKEwj2i5a5-uToAhUQqpQKHazyDm0QFjAAegQIARAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FNight_Witches&usg=AOvVaw07Zulil6nFZsaC3vYTzPwc), they would run their bombing missions under the cover of darkness. Once over the enemy fort, they would idle their engines and, while completely silent, dive towards the fort and release their payload of bombs. Only then will they pull up while also gunning their throttles to frantically escape from enemy airspace.

How would they be trained, and how long until they could complete the mission?

Comment: There are a lot of handwaved details in this story (not a criticism, not every detail needs spelling out), why do you feel this part in particular needs more input?

Comment: @LioElbammalf they need to bomb the command center to stop this needless slaughter of life.

Comment: Sure, I get that, but why do you need this bit is different to - say - training them to use rifles, machine guns and tanks. You've already passed this training without delving deeper, why is flight so different?

Comment: @LioElbammalf They can’t seem to move forward because of the dwarven steampunk-esque machinery. Solutions would be to bomb the command center (which commands the machines) or provide close air support for the ground troops in order to break the deadlock of trench warfare. The reason I specify women, is because ALL men are either dying in the trenches or working to support the men who die in the trenches. They NEED pilots, and the only people who can fulfill the role are some MAD widows.

Comment: I'm not asking why they need flight in the story I'm asking why you, the story teller, need outside input on this where training men to drive tanks and fire machine guns has already been glossed over. Women are as adaptable and trainable as men and to medieval people tanks and planes are both so far from their day to day life. How did you explain training men to drive tanks in the story so far?

Comment: @LioElbammalf I think I get what you mean. I probably shouldn’t have glossed over the other factions of ww1 warfare. I’ll need to do more research I guess. I was just enamored with the idea of widows avenging their dead husbands, sometimes surpassing their spouses’ k/d ratio. The Night Witches squadron were pretty terrifying in real life to the Germans after all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some aspects of the question are puzzling. Why would training female pilots be any different to training males? Certainly there were a number of notable female aviators in the early days of flight and no suggestion hat they would be at any disadvantage apart from the usual one of prejudice.

WW1 technology is not well-suited to producing anything like a strategic bomber force. The notable failures of bombing campaigns on both sides (like the Gotha and Giant raids on England, only marginally more successful than the disastrous Zeppelin campaign) are worth reading up on.

If there are dragons around, they are likely to be far more maneuverable than WW1 aircraft, so any encounter would likely to one-sided without appropriate weapons and tactics.

Night bombing in particular makes it virtually impossible to find a target without more sophisticated technology (this is why radio beam navigation and later radar was so important in WW2).

Hitting something as small as a fort is challenging, in WW1 they had trouble hitting something the size of a city not much better in WW2 for strategic bombers).  Also, if the magic shields can shrug off heavy artillery they would be easily proof against the relatively small bombs of this era.

Maybe look at super-long-range artillery (like the Paris Gun), or rocket artillery. Or, as it would probably work better for your plot, a parachute drop of  a commando force to storm the enemy HQ.

Comment: "*Night bombing in particular*" speaking of night bombing and women pilots, there were the [Night Witches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Night_Witches) group composed of female pilots who did night bombing during WW2. As noted, there were a number of women pilots. During WW2 there were *a lot* more women pilots than one might think. Male fighter pilots were doing the fighting, while many women did aircraft maintenance and flying planes for tests or delivery. Women were rarely acknowledged as "pilots" even though some had more flight hours and proficiency than male fighter pilot counterparts.

Answer (score 3):

> How would they be trained, and how long until they could complete the mission?

I am not a woman and being man or woman has nothing to do with the time it takes to learn piloting an aircraft.

Moreover I have only seen probably thousands of aircraft in my life so far. But having seen them doesn't give me any advantage on a person who has never seen them. We would both start from 0 and go through the needed training. I can't really imagine why having seen an aircraft or being aware of their existence would make any difference when it comes to learning how to pilot one.

The actual duration of the training strongly depends on the type of aircraft they are supposed to operate, in any case it would take several months of both theoretical and practical lessons. Aviation.SE has probably more info on that.

Answer (score 3):

If you have airplanes from Earth, then you presumably can bring over people who can fly them from Earth as well.  If you have people from Earth to fly them, they can also instruct new native pilots, just as they would train new pilots back on Earth.

Echoing L Dutch's comment, the duration of training depends on the type and complexity of the airplanes they'll be flying.  Learning to fly a modern fighter takes several years of training, including two or three levels of intermediary trainer aircraft.  On the other hand, a WWI-era trainer biplane would probably see pilots in the air after a few weeks and soloing in a couple months of constant training.  This training time would also include on-the-ground study in navigation and tactics, which would then be practiced in the air once they were comfortable at the controls.

As [a historic data-point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Night_Witches), the order creating the Night Witches was issued on October 8th, 1941, and they deployed to the front at the end of May, 1942, so almost eight months from the order being given to create the unit to an operational unit at the front.

Answer (score 2):

The good news is that the Royal Flying Corps [only needed about 50 hours](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sRVRy0jAA1Y) of flight training to make a pilot at the end of WW1. If you want WW2 level aircraft the total time increases to about 400 hours for the Allies by the end of the war.

The bad news is that you're not likely destroying much of anything with WW1 level aircraft. You'd be lucky to carry as much as the Night Witches, which only carried a few hundred kilograms each flight. Even WW2 strategic bombers or WW1 Zeppelins only carried a few thousand pounds depending on range considerations, which is why Zeppelin raids were almost entirely a propaganda tool and WW2 raids required hundreds of aircraft.

It is also debatable, even in modern times, whether or not strategic bombing is even effective in the first place without nuclear weapons(which are themselves a whole different problem). Decapitation tactics specifically barely worked in either Gulf War using smart bombs, they certainly aren't going to work using primitive weapons and aircraft from the early 20th century.